# On two variable real positive functions

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality

Suppose 
$$ H(x,y)=x \exp^{\pi y}-\frac{x(\pi-x)}{\pi}e^{xy}+(\pi-x)(\frac{\pi^2}{12}-1)e^{xy}-\frac{\pi^2}{12}x \sinh(\pi y)\\ +(1-\frac{\pi^2}{12})(\pi-x)-x,$$
$$R(x,y)=(e^{xy}-1)+\frac{(\pi-2)(\pi-x)}{2 \pi}e^{xy}.$$
With some calculating, I guess that, there exists $0.4<\alpha<0.5$ such that 
$$A)\quad H(x,y)\geq 0,\quad (x,y) \in [\alpha,\pi)\times [0, \infty)$$
and $0.4<\beta<0.5$ such that
$$B)\quad R(x,y)\geq 0,\quad (x,y) \in [\beta,\pi)\times [0, \infty)$$
$$C)\quad R(x,y)\geq 0,\quad (x,y) \in [0,\pi]\times [\frac{1}{\pi}, \infty)$$
Our main purpose is finding the proof of A, B and C and the exact value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Also we have,
$$1)\,H(0,y)=0,\, y\geq0, \qquad 2)\,H(\pi,y)\geq 0,\, y\geq 0.$$
But we can't get the complete proof.

I appreciate any solutions, comments and hints.

Comment: It seems $R(x,y)\ge 0$ for all $x\in [0,\pi], y\in [0,\infty)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\color{brown}{\mathbf{Claims\ (B), (C).}}$

Firstly, let us prove that 
$$R(x,y)\ge 0,\quad\text{if}\quad (x,y)\in[0,\pi]\times[0.\infty)$$
(pointed by **River Li**).

Really, for this constraints
$$2\pi e^{-xy}R(x,y) = 2\pi - 2\pi e^{-xy} + \pi^2-2\pi -(\pi-2)x$$
$$= \pi^2-2\pi e^{-xy} - (\pi-2)x \ge \pi^2-2\pi-(\pi-2)x = (\pi-2)(\pi-x)\ge0.$$

$\color{brown}{\mathbf{Claim\ (A).}}$

To analyze the claim $(A),$ let us consider the function
$$ H(x,y)=x e^{\pi y}-\frac{x(\pi-x)}{\pi}e^{xy}+(\pi-x)\left(\frac{\pi^2}{12}-1\right)e^{xy}-\frac{\pi^2}{12}x \sinh(\pi y)\\ +\left(1-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\right)(\pi-x)-x.$$

Since
$$\lim\limits_{y\to\infty}e^{\large -^y\!/\!_2}H(1/2,y) = \dfrac1{4\pi} - \dfrac{(2\pi-1)(12-\pi^2)}{24}- \dfrac{\pi^2}{48} < 0, $$
then should $\color{brown}{\mathbf{\alpha>0.5}}.$

Applying the notation 
$$24\pi e^{-xy}H(x,y) = 24\pi x -24x(\pi-x)+2\pi(\pi^2-12)(\pi-x) - \pi^3x(1-t^2)+(2\pi(12-\pi^2)(\pi-x)-24\pi x)t = h(x,t),$$
where 
$$t=e^{-xy},\quad t\in(0,1].$$

one can get 
\begin{align}
&h(x,t)  = 24x^2 - 2\pi^2(12-\pi^2)+2\pi(12-\pi^2)x - \pi^3x +\pi^3xt^2\\
&\qquad\qquad + 2\pi^2(12-\pi^2)t - 2\pi(12-\pi^2)xt -24\pi xt,\\
&h(x,t) = -2\pi^2(12-\pi^2) - 3\pi(\pi^2-8)x + 24 x^2 
- 2\pi(24-\pi^2)xt+\pi^3xt^2.
\end{align}

If $\underline {t=0},$ then
$$h(x,0) = h^\,_0(x) = -2\pi^2(12-\pi^2) - 3\pi(\pi^2-8)x + 24 x^2,$$
with the positive root
$$x^\,_0 = \dfrac1{48}\left(3(\pi^2-8)+\sqrt{9\pi^4-336\pi^2+2880}\right)\approx 1.740755.$$

If $\underline {t=1},$ then
$$h(x,1) = h^\,_1(x) = -2\pi^2(12-\pi^2) - 24\pi x + 24 x^2,$$
with the positive root
$$x^\,_1 = \dfrac1{6}\left(3+\sqrt{45-3\pi^2}\right)\approx 3.624958.$$

$\underline{\text{Stationary points}}$ of $h(x,t)$ correspond with the system $h'_x=h'_t=0,$ or
\begin{cases}
- 3\pi(\pi^2-8) - 2\pi(24-\pi^2)t + \pi^3t^2 + 48x = 0\\
- 2\pi(24-\pi^2)x + 2\pi^3xt = 0,
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
\pi^2t = 24-\pi^2\\
48\pi x = 3\pi^2(\pi^2-8)+(24-\pi^2)^2,
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
x_s=\dfrac{\pi^4-18\pi^2+144}{12\pi} \approx 1.691186 < x_0.\\
t_s = \dfrac{24-\pi^2}{\pi^2} \approx 1.431708.
\end{cases}

Easily to see that $H(x,y)\ge 0$ for all $y,$ iff 
$$\color{brown}{\mathbf{x\in[x_0,x_1]}}.$$