# Finding intervals for a two variable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, inequality

I had a similar question about 1 year ago, and I find more properties about my question. Now I want to ask it again and so thankful for new  solutions.
Suppose
$$ H(x,y)=x e^{\pi y}-\frac{x(\pi-x)}{\pi}e^{xy}+(\pi-x)(\frac{\pi^2}{12}-1)e^{xy}-\frac{\pi^2}{12}x \sinh(\pi y)\\ +(1-\frac{\pi^2}{12})(\pi-x)-x$$.

I guess  there exist $\alpha\geq 0$ and $\beta\geq 0$ such that
$$ H(x,y)\geq 0, \quad for \quad (x,y) \in [\alpha,\pi)\times [\beta, \infty).$$
I am looking for the best choices for  $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
With several calculations and plot graphs, I guess that if $\alpha=0$then $0.4<\beta<0.5$.

Also we have,
$$1)\,H(0,y)=0,
\qquad 2)\,H(\pi,y)= 0,
\qquad 3)H(x,0)=\frac{1}{\pi}x^2-1.$$
Furthermore $H(x,0)\geq 0$  if $x\geq \sqrt{\pi}$.

I appreciate any solutions, comments and hints.

Comment: What do you mean by best $\alpha$, $\beta$? What is the concrete criterium?

Comment: I mean at least value for Alpha and Beta. For more details, please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3432370/on-two-variable-real-positive-functions/3484190#3484190.

Answer (score 2):

A substitution $u=x/\pi$, $v=e^{\pi y}$, and $\rho=12-\pi^2$ simplifies $0\le H(x,y)$ to

$$0\le G(u,v)=2(u-1)(12u+\rho)v^u+(12+\rho)vu+(12-\rho)v^{-1}u-(24+2\rho )u+2\rho,$$

$(x,y) \in [\alpha,\pi)\times [\beta, \infty)$ iff $(u,v)\in [\alpha\pi,1)\times [e^{\pi\beta},\infty)$.

At the horizontal axis is $v$ from $1$ to $4$, at the vertical axis is $u$  from $0$ to $1$, the points with non-negative value of $g$ are red, and with negative value of $g$ are blue, the graph of a function $u=\tfrac{6-v}5$ is black.

[image]

The graph suggests that $H(x,y)\ge 0$ provided $v\ge 3.63$ ($\beta\ge 0.41$) or $u\ge  \tfrac{6-v}5$
($\alpha\ge \frac{\pi}5 \left(6-e^{\pi\beta}\right)$).

Comment: Dear Mr. Alex by A substitution $x=u\pi$, $y=(1/\pi) \ln v$, and $\rho=12-\pi^2$ and caculate $G(u, v)$, I derived  some difference between $G$  and $ H(x,y)$. Would you please guide me? I did it for 3 times and every time had same difference.

$$ G(x,y)=24((x^2/(\pi^2))+(\pi^2/12)-(x\pi/12)-1)e^{xy}+ (24/\pi)x e^{\pi y}-\pi x e^{\pi y}+\pi x e^{-\pi y}+24-2\pi x- 2\pi^2,$$ but $$H(x,y)=24((x^2/(\pi^2))+(\pi^2/12)-(2 x\pi)-1)e^{xy}+ (24\pi)x e^{\pi y}-\pi x e^{\pi y}+\pi e^{-\pi y}+24+2\pi x+ 2\pi^2- 48 x/\pi,$$.

Comment: @shabnam I calculated differently (using Mathcad) and obtained the same expression as before. But your last expression for $H(x,y)$ is wrong. For instance, in it the coefficient at $e^{xy}$ does not become $0$ when $x=\pi$, but in the expression from the question it does.

Comment: I had a mistake in the coefficient, it must be $$H(x,y)=24((x^2/ \pi^2)+(\pi^2/12)-(( x \pi)/12)-1)e^{xy}+ (24\pi)x e^{\pi y}-\pi x e^{\pi y}+\pi e^{-\pi y}+24+2\pi x+ 2\pi^2- 48 x/\pi,$$

Comment: @shabnam The coefficients at $xe^{\pm\pi y}$ in $H$ from the question are $1-\frac {\pi^2}{24}$ and $\frac {\pi^2}{24}$, whereas in $H$ from your last comment they are $24\pi-\pi$ and $\pi x^{-1}$.